# Time signatures

Tags: notation, songwriting

Can someone explain to me how to mix time signatures as a songwriter? iv'e read several articles suggesting to switch vary the time signature of a piece to give different sections contrast and variation. How would i do that as a songwriter?

Here is a brief statement i read in an article below:

"The examples above hint at the idea of mixing up different time signatures in a song. With those two we were using pairs of alternating bars to make sense of unusual time signatures, but you can also choose to simply change the time signature from one to another during the course of a song.

Sometimes this can be useful to create some variation throughout your song. It can give a track a more unique character and make the listener feel some kind of transformation in the nature of the composition.

This may make parts of the song more intense or exactly the opposite, more calm, as rhythm tends to change based on changed time signature. Alternating time signatures are a good way to make your music unique, as this technique isn’t very commonly used nowadays.

Creating alternating time signatures
When you change meters during a composition, the numbers are going to do two things. The top number will change the count that you’re actually physically counting up to, and the bottom number is going to change the rate of time.

You can experiment with changing either or both numbers, just remember when you’re changing meters and it goes from a different meter on the bottom, the note value is what changes. So if it goes from a four to an eight, you’re talking about going twice as fast, because you’re going from a quarter note value to an eighth note value. That may mean you need a tempo change too so that the change isn’t too drastic and sudden for the listener.

Using a DAW (Digital Audio Workstation) or score editing software is a great way to experiment with this idea, as you can change the time signature and immediately start hearing and seeing the impact it has on the track.

There are no rules on how many time signatures you can use in a song. Just remember not to make things too unsettled for the listener."

Comment: Not sure where you're going with this question.

Comment: This is the sixth version of essentially the same question. It is **still** no clearer what you are trying to do. Perhaps forget this idea altogether, a billion hit songs have been written in a single time signature.

Comment: essentially, im asking how do you determine what time signature a single measure of music is in? I've been studying music on my own and can't quite wrap my head around how time signatures work and apply to songwriting.

Comment: OK, find these songs on YouTube - Take Five, Dave Brubeck [straight 5/4 all the way through, but could be confusing to a beginner] Golden Brown, Stranglers, which alternates 3 bars of 3/4 then a bar of 4/4.Verses are in 3/4  [it could be counted differently but that's the lowest common denominator for simplicity]. Come back & tell us what you do or don't understand about what each is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Why you would want to mix time signatures in a composition comes down to why we use time signatures. The time signature gives you a sense of the "pulse" of the music as determined by the count and where the strong or emphasized beats are.  *(this is a generalization)*

The main emphasized beat in a time signature is the first count of the measure or bar. Depending on how many counts you have there may be additional emphasized beats.

for example, counting in 4 where the 1 is the strongest beat and 3 is the next strong beat sounds different than counting in 3 where you only have the 1 as a strong beat. *(boom chucka doom chucka vs. boom chuck chuck)*

To mix time signatures you generally want to keep a sense of the "one" or main down beat regular. Switching the feel can be done by phrases, sections or different parts of the composition.

Some examples of using changing time signatures are:

Pink Floyd - "Money"  (uses a section of 7/4)

Rush - "Tom Saywer" (switches to 7/8 from 4/4)

The Beatles - "Happiness is a Warm Gun"  (switches all over the place)

Stravinsky - "The Rite of Spring" (at the end, switches 3/16, 2/16, 3/16, 2/8)

You can also use standard Time Signatures and put in a different strong beat pattern. Some examples of this can be found in compositions from Béla Bartók where the time signature normally in 8 is listed as 3+3+2.

You can also alternate the time signature to create a different sound, as exampled by the Austrian dance music the [Zwiefacher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zwiefacher), which switches between 3 and 2 counts.